# Spark - Scala : Read json file as dataframe doesn't work when json data is spread across multiple lines?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Json Data:

```
{ "blogID" : "FJY26J1333", "date" : "2012-04-01",
"name" : "vpxnksu", "comment" : "good stuff"} 
{"blogID" : "VSAUMDFGSD", "date" : "2012-04-12", "name" : "yhftrcx", "comment" : "another comment"}
```

Code:

```
val dataFrame=sqlContext.read.json("sample.json")
dataFrame.show()
```

Output:

```
_corrupt_record       blogID      comment          date        name
{ "blogID" : "FJY...  null        null             null        null
"name" : "vpxnksu...  null        null             null        null
 null                 VSAUMDFGSD  another comment  2012-04-12  yhftrcx
```

How can i read it as two records?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its one json object per line in the source file like this:

```
{ "blogID" : "FJY26J1333", "date" : "2012-04-01", "name" : "vpxnksu", "comment" : "good stuff"} 
{ "blogID" : "VSAUMDFGSD", "date" : "2012-04-12", "name" : "yhftrcx", "comment" : "another comment"}
```

Comment: Except that you've just moved the problem, you haven't solved it.  You're probably going to want to use spark to process petabytes of multiline json text files to the file format you're suggesting, so you're back to asking how to read multiline json files using spark.